# Muitas edições suas foram rejeitadas

Tags: suporte

Olá,

Quando tentei editar uma tag ou uma pergunta recebi a seguinte mensagem:

> "Muitas edições suas foram rejeitadas."

Gostaria de saber dois pontos:

1. Gostaria de saber qual é métrica(e.g. Número de avaliações
   negativas?) para bloquear edições?
2. Quando será habilitado novamente para edição?

Comment: [Daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing): "qualquer usuário que enviar muitas edições rejeitadas terá a sugestão de outras edições vetada por 7 dias." Talvez a métrica exata não seja divulgada para que algum usuário não tente fazer as coisas forçando até o limite e então parar, para dar uma neura básica de panótica e sensação de constante vigilância

Comment: Obrigado Jefferson, vi esses “7 dias” em um post em inglês porém, ainda não entendo se o backend do site é único e configurações são globais entre os diversas áreas. Ou para português tem uma regra diferente. Quem seria os admins do site destas configurações? Algum moderador tem este nível de acesso?

Comment: eu peguei da página de ajuda do SOpt, só seguir o link